# Naming options of a Question in Quiz

Tags: question-answer, representation, questionnaire, quiz, multilingual

I am developing a Quiz, that is to be used by various candidates in 9 different languages.
So there is a dilemma in showing the options of questions:- If the options are shown as **A. B. C. D.** then how will I convert it to other languages? **I dont think translating English alphabets to other languages would convey the sequence meaning, rather should I use the alphabets of the respective languages?**

Another option would be to use **1. 2. 3. 4.** but I'm not sure on how intuitive, familiar or expressive it is to use as options of a Question in a quiz they are (as in most of the cases, we see A. B. C. D. as options)

Comment: Do all the languages involved use Arabic numbers? i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Comment: Do the cultures in question understand roman numbering? (i, ii, iii, iiii) If there are only four options you could always use a little graphic of an empty square with variants that are 1/4 filled, 1/2 filled, 3/4 filled, and fully filled. Or perhaps you could use a more abstract system like 'circle', 'triangle', 'square', 'pentagon' (ordered by number of sides). The really important question is "Is this a UI?" - Do you need numbering/lettering at all or could the answers just be different buttons?

Comment: Do your options need labels at all? Why not just show the options alone?

Comment: I agree with Ken. If you don’t need to record the answers manually, then you don’t really need ABCD as the system will record which answer was selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're over complicating things. Different languages have different ways of displaying information.

If a language, say:  Greek, or Hebrew, or Arabic or Chinese doesn't use the A,B,C,D notation structure then use what is most commonly used in that language.

If Greeks use α, β, γ, δ instead of A, B, C, D then use α, β, γ, δ.

How do you find out what is natural in different languages? Do some basic research and then test, test, test.

The testing need not be an expensive or complicated endeavor.

Comment: Yes, as you rightly mentioned, "Do some basic research and then test, test, test." That is exactly my problem. I don't have the time and bandwidth for that now and also many languages could be added in future. I cannot test then. Therefore my question: Just translation would be enough? NO. Would numbers be enough? Opinion pls.

Comment: If you're using different languages then don't you need a translator?  They shouldn't have much of a problem determining what to use.

Answer (score 1):

Numbering the question would make more sense since this is a questionnaire. This would help the participants know their progress.